# INFINISPAN :: getting bad request 400 while getting all records

Tags: node.js, infinispan

I am trying to hit my cache on qa environment and implementing the [2.1.18. Retrieving All Entries from Caches](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/rest/rest.html#rest_v2_get_entries).

Below is my curl request. I get 400 bad request.

```
 curl --location --request GET 'http://xyz/rest/v2/caches/transactionHistoryDB2?action=entries' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: 162e0596c05ab56392204538c1bcdc6b=f0bbdadd8858aaca50b60a8d5229f3bb; 5bd921f90a94eab6bd4a256140d0f6a5=e3d7675963f136abc350ba63ff90cec9' \
--header 'Content-Typea: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer Basic abcabcabcabcabcabc' \
--data-raw ''
```

In response I get `Invalid 'action' parameter supplied`.

But if I pass `?action=stats` it works.

Can anybody tell me whats wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The `--data-raw ''` argument is actually forcing your call to be a `POST` instead of a `GET`.
I used the following and it worked:

```
curl --digest -u username:password --header 'Content-Type: application/json' "http://127.0.0.1:11222/rest/v2/caches/a?action=entries"
```